# Should Durandal url hashes include the id?

Tags: durandal

Using the HTML Starter Kit example for Durandal 2.0.1.

If I add a route for customers/:id with my own vm and view I can navigate to the page c://temp/index.html#customer/123 and the page displays and in activate I can see the parameter of 123. However, the hash for that page shows as customer/:id Should the router automatically update these hashes to include any passed parameters or is this something I have to do myself?

Comment: Make sure to run the example via web server and not from the file system.

Comment: Same thing happens. When I created the route I have set nav:true, so when it displays in the shell tabs the hash is #customer/:id, which does reflect what I ask for. I think the issue is that I want dynamically created tabs as I go to #customer/123 and I am not getting them. See question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21677597/how-to-dynamically-display-tabs-for-routes-in-durandal

Comment: Looks like I miss your question. Post your router configuration, the view and the viewmodel. Please explain what you expect to happen with these in place and what happens instead.

Comment: I asked this question first, then asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21677597/how-to-dynamically-display-tabs-for-routes-in-durandal (which does have the route model and what I am trying to do). I think this question would probably be resolved if the other question gets answered. I should probably close this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a baked in fix for this but if you are going to be using the hash and you have the Id or optional Id stuff in there you can use this helper for navigation and to clean up the hash, if needed -

```
function changeRoute(route) {
    var cleanRoute = route.hash;
    if (cleanRoute.indexOf(':id') !== -1) {
        cleanRoute = cleanRoute.replace(':id', '');
    }
    return router.navigate('#' + thisRoute);
}
```

Or you could just as easily add an additional setting on the route to use as the cleaned hash.